# OTA update failing after rooting phone

Tags: updates, nexus-one, ota-update, root-access

I have an unlocked Nexus One that I rooted to remove a system application (Twitter), but now the OTA system update fails with the message

```
Verifying current system ...
assert failed: apply_patch_check("/system/app/Twitter.apk", "<long hex string>")
E:Error in /cache/c8847c98b948.signed-passion-FRG83-fromFR91.c8847c98.zip
(status 7)
```

Un-rooting the device doesn't seem to fix this. Is there more to removing a system app than doing a 'rm' of the .apk? For example, is there some configuration file that also needs patching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working was re-installing the stock Nexus One (a.k.a. Passion) image. There seem to be several different ways to go back to a stock installation, but what worked for me was:

- Download the `PASSIMG_Passion_.zip` file from [shipped-roms.com](http://shipped-roms.com/shipped/Passion%20%28Nexus%20One%29/)
- Re-name the file `passimg.zip` and copy it to the SD card via USB
- Booted into hboot (hold the volume down button while powering on the phone)
- Selected 'yes' when asked if hboot should install the image

The above steps were inspired by [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=6558753&postcount=146) post in the XDA-Developers forum. After doing this, OTA updates started working again.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to re-add the Twitter.apk, update, then remove it again.  Have you tried that?  The patch itself is trying to find that apk for the update (not sure if you can change the patch since it is probably signed?).

Comment: From what I've read, the system update removes the exploit which allows rooting the phone in the first place. My hope was to remove the app while rooting the phone was still possible.

Comment: HA! Those bastards. Don't worry there are exploits to root it and to replace the recovery as well for the OTA. www.unrevoked.com

Comment: I tried re-adding Twitter, but the update still fails with the same error.